# PointerPoint.Properties.MouseWheelDelta tilt or scroll

Tags: c#, scroll, mousewheel, winui-3

I have a function that listenes to PointerWheelChanged events of my UIElement.
I can retreive the MouseWheelDelta but this doesn't tell me if the mouse wheel was tilted or moved up/down.

How can I get this info?

This is my code to get the delta:

```cs
private void TestScrollViewer_PointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PointerPoint ptrPt = e.GetCurrentPoint((UIElement)sender);
    int delta = ptrPt.Properties.MouseWheelDelta;
    // positive: forward/right motion;  negative: backward/left motion
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IsHorizontalMouseWheel` inside `Pointers`. See this example below:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="MouseWheelTests.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:MouseWheelTests"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock x:Name="WheelHorizontal" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="WheelVertical" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid
            Grid.Row="1"
            Background="Transparent"
            PointerWheelChanged="Grid_PointerWheelChanged" />
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input;

namespace MouseWheelTests;

public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private int WheelHorizontalValue { get; set; }

    private int WheelVerticalValue { get; set; }

    private void Grid_PointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var properties = e.GetCurrentPoint((UIElement)sender).Properties;

        if (properties.IsHorizontalMouseWheel is true)
        {
            WheelHorizontalValue += properties.MouseWheelDelta;
            this.WheelHorizontal.Text = $"Horizontal: {WheelHorizontalValue}";
        }
        else
        {
            WheelVerticalValue += properties.MouseWheelDelta;
            this.WheelVertical.Text = $"Vertical: {WheelVerticalValue}";
        }
    }
}
```